# MQTT - How to know is message received by device

Tags: mqtt

We have mqtt producer and consumer.
MQTT producer is at client level.
When we push message to producer, if the device is switched on, then it will receive the message.
If the device is switched off, then it wont receive the message until it turned on.

We need to know, when message sent to MQTT in server, if server is switched off, then we need to know the status as, it is queued or not received by server.

Based on it, we will send message for the user as, Please turn on device to do specific action.

Is there any better approach to know the status in MQTT to find is message is delivered or failed or queued to know server is active or not.

Answer (score 2):

There is no end to end delivery notification in the MQTT protocol. Part of the pub/sub paradigm is that the publisher should be decoupled from the subscriber, there can be anywhere from 0 to many subscribers to a given topic.

There are 2 approaches to how to potentially work round this.

1. Have the subscriber respond on a separate topic to acknowledge that it has received the message. You will need to include a unique identifier in the message payload so it can be used in the response message.
2. You can use the Last Will and Testament feature of MQTT to have the subscriber maintain it's current status. When it starts it publishes a retained message to a known topic, e.g. publishes `true` to `consumer/12345/status` and sets a LWT to publish `false` if the device goes offline unexpectedly. It should also publish `false` if it cleanly shuts down. That way the publisher can check the status of the subscriber before deciding to publish the message.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which broker you are using. But in EMQ X MQTT broker, when QoS > 1, the message terminated delivered or ack broker will notify the server

The plugin: [emqx-web-hook](https://github.com/emqx/emqx-web-hook)